# That is the math behind interpolating circle using Bezier curve?

Tags: bezier-curve

This is a basic circle build by a graphic editor using Bézier spline. The X here is 0.552125R:

[image]

But how this value had been gotten? I mean reverse engineering, the mathematical equation which results to this value

Comment: You do not supply any information about how Beziers were used to make the circle. Without that information no one can answer.

Comment: If I have this information, I would not ask it. But it seems to be a general task, isn't it?

Comment: What is the software you used? Does it come with a manual?

Comment: Is that really matter? All that I've tried interpolates a circle like this.

Comment: You still do not give any information! You say "All that I've tried.." and then do not describe what you tried.

Comment: Blender, Inkscape for example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136421/discussion-between-coffeemath-and-crantisz).

Comment: If you search this site for “Bezier circle” you’ll find lots of material. For example this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2337392/minimizing-error-in-bézier-circle-approximation

Comment: Or this:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/873224/calculate-control-points-of-cubic-bezier-curve-approximating-a-part-of-a-circle

Comment: ok, thanks, this leads to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we have a smooth function
$$\begin{align}
f: [t_0, t_1] &\;\to\; \Bbb R^2 \\
   t &\;\mapsto\; (x(t),\,y(t)) \\
\end{align}$$
that we want to approximate by means of a cubic Bézier curve $b=b_{[P0,P1,P2,P3]}$ where the $P_i$ are the so called control points:

$$\begin{align}
b(t) &= (1-t)^3         P_0 + 3(1-t)^2t     P_1 + 3(1-t)t^2  P_2 + t^3 P_3
\end{align}$$

A reasonable choice for the control points is then:

$$\begin{align}
P_0 &= f_0\\
P_1 &= f_0 + \alpha \cdot \dot f_0\\
P_2 &= f_1 - \beta  \cdot \dot f_1\\
P_3 &= f_1\\
\end{align}$$
where $f_i = f(t_i)$ and similar notation for the derivatives.

- The 1st and 4th equation mean that $b$ and $f$ have the same starting point and the same end point.
- The 2nd and 3rd equation mean that $b$ is tangent to $f$ in the starting point and in the end point.

This means we have still a 2-dimensional space from which we can chose $b$, which is parameterized by the two parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Now there are different approaches to narrow down these two parameters; one of which is to pick a point $Q\in f$ and require $b$ to run through $Q$.

The usual parametrization of the unit circle is $f(t) = (\cos t, \sin t)$ which traverses the circle at constant speed.  So we chose $Q = f(t_{1/2}) = (1,1)/\sqrt{2}$.

Adding the requirement that $Q = f_t \stackrel!= b(t)$ to the 4 conditions from above yields the following linear system for $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

$$\begin{align}
&\binom{x_t-x_0}{y_t-y_0} + (2t^3-3t^2)\binom{x_1-x_0}{y_1-y_0}
 \\&\qquad\qquad= 3t(1-t)\binom{(1-t) \dot x_0 \quad -t \dot x_1}{(1-t) \dot y_0 \quad -t \dot y_1}\binom \alpha\beta
\end{align}$$

Solving that system is straight forward, and with $t = 1/2$ the solution reads
$$
\binom \alpha\beta = \frac 43\, \frac{1}{\dot x_1\dot y_0 - \dot x_0\dot y_1} \binom{\dot y_1 \quad  -\dot x_1}{\dot y_0 \quad -\dot x_0}
\binom{x_0+x_1-2x_{1/2}}{y_0+y_1-2y_{1/2}}  
$$
Plugging in values according to $f$ being a quarter of the unit circle, finally yields

$$
\alpha=\beta=\frac43(\sqrt2-1) \approx 0.55228475
$$

which is what you found by reverse engineering.

---

**Notice:** As I said above, there is more than one way to approach this.  A different way would be to require that the distance between $f$ and $b$ be minimal, like

$$ \max_t |f(t)-b(t)| \stackrel!= \text{minimal} $$
One problem is that $f$ and $b$ are traversed at diferent speeds, so that the $b$ you'll get from this is not the best one.  Anyway, with almost certainty you'll get different control points $P_1$ and $P_2$ an thus a different value for your $x$.